# Flatten a list within in a column in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and have the following dataframe in R:

```
     Date            Store     Sales     Product
1      1/2/2021         USA     *LIST*    TShirts
```

In the `Sales` column when I click into this on `RStudio` the table that looks like:

```
     Qtr            Sales     Revenue     Profit
1     1              1000       10000       2000
2     2              1000       10000       2000
3     3              1000       10000       2000
4     4              1000       10000       2000
```

How can I flatten this dataframe to create an extra 12 columns so the expected output is:

```
      Date              Store     Sales     Product      Qtr1.Sales   Qtr1.Revenue    etc etc
1      1/2/2021         USA     *LIST*    TShirts          1000           10000
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you provide data using `dput` so that we know how is your data stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` within a `map` call:

```
library(tidyverse)

sales_data <- tibble(
  Qtr = 1:4,
  Sales = 1000,
  Revenue = 10000,
  Profit = 2000
)

data <- tibble(
  date = as.Date("2021-02-01"),
  Store = "US",
  Sales = list(sales_data),
  Product = "TShirts"
)

data
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   date       Store Sales            Product
#>   <date>     <chr> <list>           <chr>  
#> 1 2021-02-01 US    <tibble [4 x 4]> TShirts

data %>%
  mutate(Sales = map(Sales, ~{
    .x %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = -Qtr, names_to = "key", values_to = "value") %>%
      mutate(key = str_c(key, Qtr, sep = ".")) %>%
      select(-Qtr) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value)
  })) %>%
  unnest(cols = Sales)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 15
#>   date       Store Sales.1 Revenue.1 Profit.1 Sales.2 Revenue.2 Profit.2 Sales.3
#>   <date>     <chr>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 2021-02-01 US       1000     10000     2000    1000     10000     2000    1000
#> # ... with 6 more variables: Revenue.3 <dbl>, Profit.3 <dbl>, Sales.4 <dbl>,
#> #   Revenue.4 <dbl>, Profit.4 <dbl>, Product <chr>
```